# python TKinter combobox autocomplete

Tags: python, combobox, autocomplete, tkinter

I am trying to create a combobox and an entry widget, which is dependent on the combobox. To be more precise: the user should select a value in the combobox and the entry widget serves data dependent on the combobox with an autocomplete function. I have found the autocomplete source code here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578253-an-entry-with-autocompletion-for-the-tkinter-gui/

Here is what I have done so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk, os, re
root = Tk()
root.minsize(500,300)
root.maxsize(550,310)



class AutocompleteEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, lista, *args, **kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.lista = lista
        print "lista in autocom " + str(lista)
        self.var = self["textvariable"]
        if self.var == '':
            self.var = self["textvariable"] = StringVar()
        self.var.trace('w', self.changed)
        self.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
        self.bind("<Up>", self.up)
        self.bind("<Down>", self.down)

        self.lb_up = False


    def changed(self, name, index, mode):
        if self.var.get() == '':
            self.lb.destroy()
            self.lb_up = False
        else:
            words = self.comparison()
            print words
            if words:
                if not self.lb_up:
                    self.lb = Listbox()
                    self.lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.place(x=self.winfo_x(), y=self.winfo_y()+self.winfo_height())
                    self.lb_up = True

                self.lb.delete(0, END)
                for w in words:
                    self.lb.insert(END,w)
            else:
                if self.lb_up:
                    self.lb.destroy()
                    self.lb_up = False

    def selection(self, event):
        if self.lb_up:
            self.var.set(self.lb.get(ACTIVE))
            self.lb.destroy()
            self.lb_up = False
            self.icursor(END)

    def up(self, event):
        if self.lb_up:
            if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.lb.curselection()[0]
            if index != '0':
                self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index)-1)
                self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                self.lb.activate(index)

    def down(self, event):
        if self.lb_up:
            if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.lb.curselection()[0]
            if index != END:
                self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index)+1)
                self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                self.lb.activate(index)

    def comparison(self):
        pattern = re.compile(self.var.get() + '.*')
        return [w for w in self.lista if re.match(pattern, w)]




class MyListbox:

    lista = ['a', 'actions', 'additional', 'also', 'an', 'and', 'angle', 'are', 'as', 'be', 'bind', 'bracket', 'brackets', 'button', 'can', 'cases', 'configure', 'course', 'detail', 'enter', 'event', 'events', 'example', 'field', 'fields', 'for', 'give', 'important', 'in', 'information', 'is', 'it', 'just', 'key', 'keyboard', 'kind', 'leave', 'left', 'like', 'manager', 'many', 'match', 'modifier', 'most', 'of', 'or', 'others', 'out', 'part', 'simplify', 'space', 'specifier', 'specifies', 'string;', 'that', 'the', 'there', 'to', 'type', 'unless', 'use', 'used', 'user', 'various', 'ways', 'we', 'window', 'wish', 'you']


    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title(title)
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closes)
        self.cities = ['New York', 'Vienna', 'Miami', 'Oslo']

        self.establishment()

    def combobox_handler(self, event):
        current = self.combobox.current()
        print self.combobox.get()
        self.entNumber.delete(0, END)

        print self.lista
        self.entNumber = AutocompleteEntry(self.lista, self.parent)



    def establishment(self):
        mainFrame = Frame(self.parent)
        mainFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        fr_left = Frame(mainFrame, bd=10)
        fr_left.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=LEFT)

        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(fr_left, values=self.cities)
        self.combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.combobox_handler)
        self.combobox.pack()

        fr_right = Frame(mainFrame, bd=10)
        fr_right.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=RIGHT)

        fr_up = Frame(fr_right)
        fr_up.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES)


        self.entNumber = Entry()
        self.entNumber.place(x=50, y=100)

    def closes(self, event=None):
        self.parent.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyListbox(root, "Main Window")
    root.mainloop()
```

The code is just for testing.

The problem is, that the program stops in the **init** of autocompleteEntry() without any error. Can someone give me a hint, what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in anticipation!
Stefan

Comment: do you see your print? ... `self["textvariable"]` seems wrong ... are you sure its not `self.textvariable`

Comment: yes, I have found the code here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578253-an-entry-with-autocompletion-for-the-tkinter-gui/

Comment: and it is working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that after selecting an entry in the combobox, even though you are creating the `AutocompleteEntry` , but you are not positioning it anywhere , so it is not showing up . You would need to place it somewhere for it to show up.

Example -

```
self.entNumber1 = AutocompleteEntry(self.lista, self.parent)
self.entNumber1.place(x=50, y=120)
```

To place it right below the entry called `entNumber`.

---

Or you can simple create `AutoCompleteEntry` from the start in `self.entNumber` , but that all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Anand. That is exactly what I needed. I thought it is sufficient to place it in the establishment().

Comment: @Stefan: Probably, but you redefine `self.entNumber` in this line `self.entNumber = Entry()`

Comment: @Stefan Yes, when you create AutoCompleteEntry again in the handler, its a completely new object, just because you assign it back to the old name does not mean it would take properties of the old object. It would just directly replace the old entry, thats it, and you would lose reference to that entry.